# How to get rid of rows with pandas in a CSV where the value of cells in a specific column is under 100 Billion?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to filter through a CSV and make a new CSV which is the exact same except for it gets rid of any rows that have a value of greater than 100 billion in the 'marketcap' column.

The code I've written so just spits out the same CSV as the original out over again and doesn't cut out any lines from the old CSV to the new CSV.

Code:

```
db = pd.read_csv('SF1_original.csv')
db = db[db['marketcap']<= 100000000000]
db.to_csv('new_SF1_original.csv')
```

Example of old CSV (It's long don't look through whole thing, just to give you an idea):

```
ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,reportperiod,lastupdated,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
A,ARQ,1999-12-31,2000-03-15,2000-01-31,2020-09-01,53000000,7107000000,,4982000000,2125000000,,10.219,-30000000,1368000000,1368000000,1160000000,131000000,2.41,0.584,665000000,111000000,554000000,665000000,281000000,96000000,0,0.0,0.0,202000000,298000000,0.133,298000000,202000000,202000000,0.3,0.3,0.3,4486000000,,4486000000,50960600000,,,354000000,0.806,1.0,1086000000,0.484,0,0,4337000000,,1567000000,42000000,42000000,0,2621000000,2067000000,554000000,51663600000,1368000000,-160000000,2068000000,111000000,0,1192000000,-208000000,-42000000,384000000,0,131000000,131000000,131000000,0,0,0.058,915000000,171000000,635000000,0.0,11.517,,,1408000000,0,114.3,,,1445000000,131000000,2246000000,2246000000,290000000,,,,,0,625000000,1.0,452000000,439000000,440000000,5.116,7107000000,0,71000000,113000000,16.189,2915000000
```

Example New CSV (Exact same when this line should have been cut):

```
,ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,reportperiod,lastupdated,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
0,A,ARQ,1999-12-31,2000-03-15,2000-01-31,2020-09-01,53000000.0,7107000000.0,,4982000000.0,2125000000.0,,10.219,-30000000.0,1368000000.0,1368000000.0,1160000000.0,131000000.0,2.41,0.584,665000000.0,111000000.0,554000000.0,665000000.0,281000000.0,96000000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,202000000.0,298000000.0,0.133,298000000.0,202000000.0,202000000.0,0.3,0.3,0.3,4486000000.0,,4486000000.0,50960600000.0,,,354000000.0,0.8059999999999999,1.0,1086000000.0,0.484,0.0,0.0,4337000000.0,,1567000000.0,42000000.0,42000000.0,0.0,2621000000.0,2067000000.0,554000000.0,51663600000.0,1368000000.0,-160000000.0,2068000000.0,111000000.0,0.0,1192000000.0,-208000000.0,-42000000.0,384000000.0,0.0,131000000.0,131000000.0,131000000.0,0.0,0.0,0.057999999999999996,915000000.0,171000000.0,635000000.0,0.0,11.517000000000001,,,1408000000.0,0.0,114.3,,,1445000000.0,131000000.0,2246000000.0,2246000000.0,290000000.0,,,,,0.0,625000000.0,1.0,452000000.0,439000000.0,440000000.0,5.1160000000000005,7107000000.0,0.0,71000000.0,113000000.0,16.189,2915000000.0
```

I've seen two questions somewhat related to this on StackOverflow, but they haven't helped me much. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623009/delete-rows-in-csv-based-on-specific-column-value-python) uses CSV library instead of pandas (which is an option for me). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068265/how-to-sort-csv-rows-by-a-single-column-using-pandas-python) is more helpful since it uses pandas but still hasn't been interacted with and isn't exactly the same as my use case.

Comment: You might need to convert `marketcap` column to integer before filtering. Try something like this : `db = db.astype({'marketcap': int})`

Comment: I tried that and I get this error: ValueError: ```Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer```

Comment: try using `np.where` https://stackoverflow.com/q/53040174

Comment: I'm confused as to how and where I would implement that in my code. ```db['marketcap'} = np.where(db['marketcap'] == ```

and then I'm not too sure what to make it equal to. In the question link that was sent, .where is attempting to change the value of cells, so how would I change them to integers so that I can work with them?

Comment: @george.adams1 its because there are rows with empty columns. You can remove them by calling `db.dropna(inplace=True)` after reading the dataframe

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi how do I make that specific to the 'marketcap' column?

Comment: @george.adams1 Using this : `db.dropna(subset=['marketcap'], inplace=True)`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I tried that, my code was: ```db = db.dropna(subset=['marketcap'], inplace=True)
db = db.astype({'marketcap':int})```

I got an error for the astype part: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'```

I looked up this link but it doesn't seem to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273464/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-astype.

Comment: `db.dropna(subset=['marketcap', inplace=True]` without assigning

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I'm not entirely sure what that means. There is no second () in that line of code. Can you clarify where the [ ] and ( ) go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225338/discussion-between-george-adams1-and-amine-messaoudi).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indexes of the rows with `"marketcap"` over 100 billion rows like so:

```
df.loc[df["marketcap"] > 100000000000]["marketcap"].index
```

All that's left to do is drop them from the `DataFrame`:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df["marketcap"] > 100000000000]["marketcap"].index, inplace=True)
```

Reading from CSV and writing to the CSV is already correctly taken care of in your code.

Comment: The df that you wrote are supposed to be db right?

Comment: @george.adams1 yes

Comment: @gmdevI keep getting a recurring issue of not being able to turn the cells in the file into integers in order to use the code that you showed above in order to drop the lines over 100billion in the csv. ```x['marketcap'] = [['marketcap']] = db.apply(pd.to_numeric(db))
 db = db.astype({'marketcap':int})``` 

I keep getting the error ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'```

Comment: @george.adams1 do you have missing values in your CSV?

Comment: I do but I already used ```db = db.dropna(subset=['marketcap'], inplace=True)``` to get rid of them

Comment: @george.adams1 what's the reason `for x=y=z` (`x['marketcap'] = [['marketcap']] = db.apply(pd.to_numeric(db))`)?